# How can I retrieve related or upselling products in php shopify app?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I am looking into these apis to develop my shopify app, they haven't mentioned about apis for getting upselling products. Can anyone help?
https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php
https://github.com/ShopifyExtras/PHP-Shopify-API-Wrapper

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for this kind of questions. Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in Shopify as **related products**. You make the relations up yourself. Since early days of Shopify, many concepts have been used to upsell related products, all of them based off of nothing more than simplistic concepts like connecting by type, vendor, sales quantity, or simple curation links.